# Couldnt create a new JSONObject(); Where am i going wrong

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, gson

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

@WebServlet("/GetJSONUser")
public class GetJSONUser extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("##QUERY STRING(Get): "+request.getQueryString());
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        Gson json = new Gson();
        ArrayList<User> userList = UserService.GetUserList(getServletContext());
        try{
        JSONObject responseData = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray cellArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray cell = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject cellObject = new JSONObject();

        for(int i=0;i<userList.size();i++)
        {
            cellObject.put("id",i+1);

            cell = new JSONArray();
            cell.add(userList.get(i).id);
            cell.add( userList.get(i).username);
            cell.add(userList.get(i).roleId);

            cellObject.put("cell", cell);
            cellArray.add(cellObject);
        }

        responseData.put("page", 1);
        responseData.put("total", 1);
        responseData.put("records ", userList.size());
        responseData.put("rows", cellObject);
        String jsonReturn = json.toJson(responseData);
        System.out.println(jsonReturn);
        writer.print(jsonReturn);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("##QUERY STRING: "+request.getParameterMap());
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        Gson json = new Gson();
        ArrayList<User> userList = UserService.GetUserList(getServletContext());
        String jsonReturn = json.toJson(userList);
        System.out.println(jsonReturn);
        writer.print(jsonReturn);
    }
}
```

**Error:**

Source not found

the source attached does not contain the source for the file ApplicationFilterChain.class

When it reaches the line

JSONObject responseData = new JSONObject();

[image]

both Gson.jar and json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar are in lib folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
```

try

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
```

Comment: But GSON's JSONArray can only add a Json Element

Comment: JsonElement is a base abstract class. So you can use its implementations: JsonArray, JsonNull, JsonObject and JsonPrimitive.

Comment: How to resolve this line </br>

cell = new JsonArray();

   cell.add(userList.get(i).id);

Comment: i used     gson.toJsonTree(userList.get(i).id); to generate JsonElement